# CSS hover on image even though it's not included

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, hover

this is my html

```
<div class="homeimage">
  <%= link_to image_tag("resizelogo_2.png", alt: "XYZ logo") %>
</div>
```

this is the corresponding css

```
div.homeimage {
  margin-left: 85px;
}
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsDsk.png) is what it should look like.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zmG1.png) is what it looks like hovering over the image. I assume there has to be some sort of default setting when it comes to hovering? I know that I could use the .nohover within the class but that should only be needed if I explicitly included hover in the class right? How can I get rid of the hover?

update:

```
<a href="https://MYc9USER.c9users.io/">
<img alt="XYZ logo" src="/assets/resizelogo_2-796d8a59a387f11e56e2d1edcc4d8443aaa4fead3f224b73e1d8a65e58281b06.png"></a>
```

Comment: Use inspect element to check which class is altering the behavior, post the code here.

Comment: @ElieNassif included it in the original post. so obviously the href hovers I guess? I mean href should hover - just not in this case...

Comment: Do you still get this behavior when you remove the Anchor?

Comment: oh my god... just realised the "link_to" in my first listing. removed it and obviously the href disappeared as well. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No problem mate :) I'll post the answer below for people to read in case they're too lazy to look at the comments lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the link_to that creates an anchor wrap around the image.

Answer (score 1):

Anything in html can have a hover state.
You have to first find out what is triggering the effect you want to get rid of.

You can do that using the dev tools.

[image]

Once you find out what is causing the hover you can override it using css:

```
.classname:hover {
 color: pink;
}
```